# Where is the kaggle competitions submodule?

Tags: kaggle

I am new to the `kaggle` python module and do not understand the structure. I am trying to execute the following command from a sample script [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dster/two-sigma-news-official-getting-started-kernel), but when I try to run the `import` it fails:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaggle.competitions'
```

I used `pip3` to install the module originally and did not have any errors in my install. Additionally, I can run `import kaggle` without errors, and I can use the command line interface for `kaggle` to download datasets. I looked at the github repository and also do not see a directory named competitions or a `competitions.py`. Can someone explain to me what step I missed here to have a `competitions` submodule? Is there an install script I should have run but didn't?

Also I tried iterating through the submodules of `kaggle` like this:

```
>>> l = [l for l in pkgutil.walk_packages(path = kaggle.__path__, 
>>> [r[1] for r in l]
['api', 'api.kaggle_api', 'api.kaggle_api_extended', 'api_client', 'cli', 'configuration', 'models', 'models.dataset_column', 'models.dataset_new_request', 'models.dataset_new_version_request', 'models.dataset_upload_file', 'models.error', 'models.kaggle_models_extended', 'models.kernel_push_request', 'models.result', 'rest', 'tests', 'tests.test_authenticate']
```

But I don't see any `competitions` so not sure where to go from here. I'd welcome suggestions. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you're trying to use is only available in the Kernels environment and it's specific to that particular competition. It's a custom module used to interact with this competition's dataset within the Kernels environment.

By contrast, the module you're `pip` installing is [Kaggle's public API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api).

I hope that helps clarify the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I eventually figured it was something like this, but it would be helpful if the modules did not share the same name....